# How to plot 2D array inside 3D array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, plot

Suppose you have a 3D array like this:

```
[[['1', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3']], 
 [['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['3', '3']], 
 [['2', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '4'], ['2', '5']]]
```

Each 2D array is the x,y coordinates of a line. The 3D array is the compilation of lines in the data set. How can you plot each 2D array separately from the entire array? In other words, how can you plot a line with coordinates (1,1),(1,2),1,3) and another line (3,1),(3,2),(3,3), and so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([val1[0]  for val1 in lst_source[0] ], [val1[1]  for val1 in lst_source[0] ])
plt.plot([val1[0]  for val1 in lst_source[1] ], [val1[1]  for val1 in lst_source[1] ])
```